# Поиск одинаковых элементов в бинарном поиске после Python

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделать, чтобы бинарный поиск в программе продолжался дальше, если искомый элемент уже найден.  Например, нужно найти число 2. А оно встречается три раза в списке.
Спасибо!

Comment: Стандартный модуль bisect используете или свой алгоритм реализуете?

Comment: В двоичном поиске здорового человека нет сравнения на равенство, только на неравенство. Такой поиск продолжается пока не будет найдено подходящее место для вставки нового элемента.

Comment: Использую свой алгоритм. Без функций. Только while..(If...else). И логические операторы

Answer (score 0):

в зависимости от вашего кода конечно, но вы можете оформить что-то типа этого:
Поиск в таблице чисел.

```py
def grade(score, breakpoints=(60, 70, 80, 90), grades='FDCBA'):
     i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
     return grades[i]

[grade(score) for score in [33, 99, 77, 70, 89, 90, 100]]
['F', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку бинарный поиск делается в отсортированном списке, то после нахождения нужного элемента бинарным поиском просто проходите по списку сначала влево от найденного элемента, пока элементы списка совпадают с искомым, а потом точно так же вправо.

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7]
             ^
             | например, бинарный поиск найдёт этот элемент
```

Comment: Это плохой совет - получится линейная сложность. А границы диапазона равных элементов отыскиваются за два логарифма.

Comment: И правильный бинарный поиск всегда отыскивает или первую двойку в вашем примере или последнюю. [bisect_left](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left), [bisect_right](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да в общем согласен, но если как в постановке задачи повторяющихся цифр мало, а свой двоичный поиск писать лениво, то пойдёт )